# freebsd dmesg has a lot of "Limiting icmp unreach response from 1293 to 200 packets/sec"

Tags: networking, freebsd, icmp

I has a simple freebsd 9.0 machine.But everytime i start my freebsd and use command dmesg. There aren't any hardware information there but full of

```
         "Limiting icmp unreach response from 1293 to 200 packets/sec"
```

there.

Does any one there can tell me why this happen? And how can i erase this ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry. for my poor english.

Comment: What is the server doing? When does it happen? (All the time? Only when you run specific networking testing or analysis tools?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your machine is being hit by UDP packets which are destined to closed ports. So, it is generating ICMP unreachable responses and this message tells you that the current limit 200 packets/sec has been reached. You need to find the reason of such a traffic. Packet capturing tools like tcpdump/wireshark are very useful to diagnose such problems. You can find the packets received by your machine and who is sending them.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can disable this messages by sysctl:

```
sysctl net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
sysctl net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
```

More info in `man blackhole`

Add those lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make those changes persistent.